# How to calculate water pressure (Kpa/Mpa/PSI) with depth in the Biofloc fish farming?

Tags: ichthyology

Can you tell us a little bit about the water pressure (Kpa/Mpa/PSI) with depth in the Biofloc fish farming and the calculation of Kpa ​​/ PSI / Mpa so that one can understand which air pump machine should to buy.

Comment: this is not a biology question,here is how to calculate the pressure your air pump need to overcome https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/hydrostatic-pressure-water-d_1632.html

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about biology. Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

In round numbers fresh water is 2 ft for 1 psi. For example 50 ft depth requires 25 psi to barely push out an air bubble. There are other factors like resistance of an air diffuser ,etc.  If that is a little too "round" , use 0.866 psi for 2 ft . Fresh water = 62.4 pounds/cubic foot; a square ft is 144 square inches , so 62.4/144 = pounds/sq.in at one foot depth (0.433) . Then for salt water replace the fresh density with your salt density.